# Cannot get my div to be set left with JavaScript css scripting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to change the left css style dynamically as I want it to be reactionary to the amount of divs in the front end. However I cannot get this to be set as I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined".

This is my CSS which works perfectly fine

```
.brand .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: 0;
}

.brand .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -100%;
}

.brand .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -200%;
}
```

I have also been able to set the width dynamically in the same javascript file with

```
var count = $(".brand .slider__inner >div").length;
var width = count * 100;
$('.brand .slider__inner').width(width + '%');
```

However when I got to set the sixth radio button it does not want to work for me. I have tried code such as `.style.left` `.css()` `.left` etc but cant seem to get the right code that'll work.

```
var x = 6;
var left = -(6 - 1) * 100;
 $('.brand .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(x) ~ .slider__inner ').style.left =left+'%';
```

Here is a jsfiddle where I've set it up so CSS file can make all the radio buttons work apart from the 5th one. The fifth one is the one I am trying to manipulate with Javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/joel081112/fb2zyru1/11/

Comment: You're confusing jQuery and vanilla JS. Either use `document.querySelector(...).style.left` or use jQuery's `.css('left', ...)`

Comment: @ChrisG  See I tried the Jquery one and it didnt work. Ill give the queryselector a try

Comment: @ChrisG `document.querySelector('.brand .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(x) ~ .slider__inner ').style.left =left+'%';` I tried this and it didnt work?

Comment: Please edit your question and create a [mre].

Comment: @ChrisG see the edit now has a a jsfiddle example with the javascript not working for the left property

Comment: Ok, here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/tur36dz4/ (yours didn't work because the selector only matches a checked 5th child, which doesn't exist at the time the code runs)

Comment: Didn't you look at my fiddle?

Comment: @ChrisG sorry think I am half asleep. That is awesome thank you!